# Count total flow inventory in and out php mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**For the record I'm not using different table, I calculate using the same table but I added more column called stock.**

I have a record table:

```
Table A
=======================================================
**id** | **code** | **status** | **total** | **date** |
1      | B01      | IN         | 500       |2013-01-15|
2      | B01      | OUT        | 100       |2013-01-20|
3      | B01      | OUT        | 200       |2013-02-01|
4      | B01      | IN         | 300       |2013-02-05|
```

The output that I want using select mysql is like this:

```
Table A
==================================================================
**id** | **code** | **status** | **total** | **date** | **stock**  
1      | B01      | IN         | 500       |2013-01-15| 500       
2      | B01      | OUT        | 100       |2013-01-20| 400       
3      | B01      | IN         | 200       |2013-02-01| 600       
4      | B01      | OUT        | 300       |2013-02-05| 300
```

As you can see I added the stock column in table A.. so my question is how can I achieved that using mysql ?

**UPDATE**

I've been saved by @Juergen D answer so I'm using his method:

```
select t.*, @stock := @stock + case when status = 'IN' 
                                    then total
                                    else -total  
                               end as stock
from your_table t
cross join (select @stock := 0) s
order by t.id
```

in case you  have a same problem as me :)

Comment: Are you trying to modify the "record" table or simply select from two tables?

Comment: You would use [`COUNT()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/) or [`SUM()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/)

Comment: I think modify with add 1 more column like above @KodleeYin

Comment: yes, and I need how to do it, could you help me ? @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t.*, @stock := @stock + case when status = 'IN' 
                                    then total
                                    else -total  
                               end as stock
from your_table t
cross join (select @stock := 0) s
order by t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement inside of `SUM` to determine whether to add or subtract.

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.code,
    t1.status,
    t1.date,
    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN t2.status = 'IN'
        THEN t2.total
        WHEN t2.status = 'OUT'
        THEN (t2.total * -1)
        END
    ) stock
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2
    ON t2.date <= t1.date
    AND t2.code = t1.code
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not a different table, it's just the same table but I added more column

Comment: @EkaRudiAnto I know, the query above does a self join to the same table

Comment: really ? well I'm a newbie for mysql I think :) thank you for your help though :) - @FuzzyTree