# total inventory stock mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a follow up question about this question of mine if you don't mind..

[count total flow inventory in and out php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354891/count-total-flow-inventory-in-and-out-php-mysql)

```
Table A
=======================================================
**id** | **code** | **status** | **total** | **date** |
1      | B01      | IN         | 500       |2013-01-15|
2      | B01      | OUT        | 100       |2013-01-20|
3      | B01      | OUT        | 200       |2013-02-01|
4      | B01      | IN         | 300       |2013-02-05|
```

from the table above I would like the output like this..

```
Table A
===================================================================================
**id** | **code** | **status** | **total** | **date** | **stock** | 1st month stock
1      | B01      | IN         | 500       |2013-01-15| 500       | -
2      | B01      | OUT        | 100       |2013-01-20| 400       | 500
3      | B01      | IN         | 200       |2013-02-01| 600       | 400
4      | B01      | OUT        | 300       |2013-02-05| 300       | 600
5      |          |            |           |          |           | 300
```

how can I achieve that using mysql ? is there a way?

for the stock column I'm already achieve that using this method

```
select t.*, @stock := @stock + case when status = 'IN' 
                                    then total
                                    else -total  
                               end as stock
from your_table t
cross join (select @stock := 0) s
order by t.id
```

from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354891/count-total-flow-inventory-in-and-out-php-mysql), help me I'm really new to mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you already have, you could add another expression to the SELECT list,

```
select t.*, @stock AS `1st month stock`, @stock := ...
```

N.B. the return of the current value of `@stock` would need to come BEFORE a new value is assigned to `@stock` in the SELECT list, so the order of the columns is slightly different than shown in the desired output.

---

Based on your current query, just add a new expression to your SELECT list, to return another column, e.g.

```
select t.*
     , @stock AS `1st month stock`
     , @stock := @stock + case when status = 'IN' 
                                then total
                                else -total  
                           end as stock
from your_table t
cross join (select @stock := 0) s
order by t.id
```

Comment: could you give me an example for that matter ? @spencer7593

Comment: @Eka RudiAnto: based on your example data and example output, all that is required is to add an expression to the SELECT list of your current query (that is, if what you want is the value of `@stock` as it was returned on the previous row.) I added the full query to my answer.

Comment: it didn't return with another row on below but overall it works man :) thanks, but I still don't understand why is it work ? could you recommend me a good article about it? if it's not convenient with you that it is okay.. :) thank you for your help...

Comment: @Eka RudiAnto: The reference to the user variable `@stock` works just like it does in the expression you're already using it in. The reference returns the current value of the variable _at the time_ the variable is referenced. Note that this is MySQL specific behavior, and the behavior is _NOT_ guaranteed.  The inline view (aliased as `s`) in your query gets evaluated first, and a value of `'0'` is assigned to `@stock`. When that's referenced on the first row processed by the SELECT list in the outer query, it returns `0`. Each subsequent reference gets the current value.